# VK Api отобразить фото из профиля

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, android-sdk, вконтакте

Мне нужно отобразить фото своего профиля vk в любой прокручивающейся вьюшке (Recycler/List). Но, так как я в VKApi совсем уж новичок, возникли некоторые проблемы. Я пытаюсь вывести в консоль студии хотя бы список фоток, но пока не особо получается. Вот кидаю свой MainActivity класс. ID страницы единичка, чтобы просто не палиться - так пишу свое. Проверял в документации - выводит мои фотки, все нормально.

P.S. Данный код исправно работал с выводом текстов постов группы, а тут что-то не сошлось.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.vk.sdk.VKAccessToken;
import com.vk.sdk.VKCallback;
import com.vk.sdk.VKSdk;
import com.vk.sdk.api.VKApiConst;
import com.vk.sdk.api.VKError;
import com.vk.sdk.api.VKParameters;
import com.vk.sdk.api.VKRequest;
import com.vk.sdk.api.VKResponse;
import com.vk.sdk.api.model.VKPhotoArray;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        VKSdk.login(this);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (!VKSdk.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new VKCallback<VKAccessToken>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(final VKAccessToken res) {
                VKRequest vkRequest = new VKRequest("photos.getAll",VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.OWNER_ID, 1), VKPhotoArray.class);
                vkRequest.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                        super.onComplete(response);

                        System.out.println();
                        VKRequest request = new VKRequest("photos.getAll", VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.OWNER_ID, 1), VKPhotoArray.class);
                        request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                                super.onComplete(response);

                                try {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) response.json.get("response");
                                    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("items");
                                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                                        JSONObject post = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                                        System.out.println(post.get("src"));
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(VKError error) {

            }
        })) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "возникли некоторые проблемы" - очень хороший вопрос ) Я думаю вам просто нужно сделать некоторые исправления ) А серьёзно - никаких ошибок, никакого описания что вообще не так. Плюс вот это "onActivityResult" - вы уверены что оно вообще вызывается? Я конечно с андроидом работал давненько, но ЕМНИП он вызывается при закрытии другой активити. А я у вас ничего такого не вижу. Да и вообще я бы на вашем месте запустил бы отладчик или понаставлял бы логов, чтобы посмотреть, действительно ли вы правильно всё вызываете..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделать это можно примерно так:

```
private void VkRequest() {
    VKRequest request = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "photo_200"));
    request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            VKApiUser user = ((VKList<VKApiUser>) response.parsedModel).get(0);
            String urlImage = user.photo_200;
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(VKError error) {}
        @Override
        public void attemptFailed(VKRequest request, int attemptNumber, int totalAttempts) {}
    });
}
```

Все опциональные параметры можно найти [здесь](https://vk.com/dev/objects/user) и [здесь](https://vk.com/dev/objects/user_2).